# How can i add classes to classpath with gradle?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit4

I had a Spring MVC project with XML configurations base, and i change that for Java code ones. But the problem is, i have a `ApplicationContextTest` where there are specifics configurations for test.
But when i run `gradle test` this fail with this error:

```
/home/karim/Workspace/spring-project/src/test/java/org/my-com/my-project/services/PhoneServiceTest.java:13: error: package config does not exist
import config.ApplicationContextTest;
             ^
/home/karim/Workspace/spring-project/src/test/java/org/my-com/my-project/services/PhoneServiceTest.java: error: cannot find symbol
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ApplicationContextTest.class)
                              ^
```

I think i understand what this error means, there is no `config` package in my classpath right?

The `ApplicationContextTest` class is at `src/test/resources/config`. So how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources folder is for... resources (images, properties files, etc.). Source files go in `src/test/java`.